# Stable implementation of Stooge Sort?

Tags: algorithm

Is that actually possible? I found it in wikipedia under inneficient sorts, but I can't yet visualise the process perfectly so I don't know what I'd have to change to make it stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that there is only one step of [Stooge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stooge_sort) that actually changes the order of elements: the first one.  The remaining steps are all recursion steps.  Changing any of the recursion steps would change the fundamental character of the algorithm, such that it would no longer be stooge sort if we didn't recurse in this way (the three recursive calls seem quintessentially "stoogey.")

The first step is also very simple, and changing it would seem to change the character of the algorithm as well.  But we can make a tweak to it: if the initial element is greater than the final element, swap the first element *A* that is equal to the final element with the last element before *A* equal to the initial element, which we can find via a single pass.  Surprisingly, even though the inner loop is now O(*n*) instead of O(1), the [Master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) shows us that the complexity remains the same at O(*n*^2.71).  It is also true that if all the elements are unique, the same sequence of swaps will occur as in the original Stooge Sort, which makes this version a close cousin.

To quickly sketch why this version is stable, consider a reordering of two equal elements to be a "bad swap".  We claim that there are no bad swaps using the above approach.  The reason is that for any swap, we know that there is no element between the two elements equal to either element.  Since equal elements remain in the same order, the algorithm is stable.

The proof that the algorithm is correct is similar to the proof of correctness of the original Stooge Sort.  This is a common homework question, so I don't want to give it away, but it follows from the inductive hypothesis.

In case the description of the tweak was a bit terse, a Java implementation follows.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class StableStooge {
    public static class FooBar implements Comparable<FooBar> {
        public final int foo;
        public final int bar;

        public FooBar(int foo, int bar) {
            this.foo = foo;
            this.bar = bar;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(FooBar arg0) {
            return foo - arg0.foo;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return foo +":"+bar;
        }
    }

    private static void sort(Comparable[] c, int start, int end) {
        if (start >= end) return;
        if (c[start].compareTo(c[end]) > 0) {
            // Find the first thing X equal to end and the last thing Y which is before X and equal to start
            int lastindex = end;
            int firstindex = start;
            for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
                if (c[end].compareTo(c[i]) == 0) {
                    lastindex = i;
                    break;
                } else if (c[start].compareTo(c[i]) == 0) {
                    firstindex = i;
                }
            }
            Comparable tmp = c[firstindex];
            c[firstindex] = c[lastindex];
            c[lastindex] = tmp;
        }
        // Recurse
        if (end - start + 1 >= 3) { 
            int third = (end - start + 1) / 3;
            sort(c, start, end-third);
            sort(c, start+third, end);
            sort(c, start, end-third);
        }
    }

    public static void sort(Comparable[] c) {
        sort(c, 0, c.length-1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FooBar[] test = new FooBar[100];
        FooBar[] testsav = new FooBar[100];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < test.length; j++) {
                test[j] = new FooBar(r.nextInt(10), j);
                testsav[j] = test[j];
            }
            sort(test);
            // verify
            for (int j = 1; j < test.length; j++) {
                if (test[j].foo < test[j-1].foo) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Bad sort");
                }
                if (test[j].foo == test[j-1].foo && test[j].bar <= test[j-1].bar) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Unstable sort: "+Arrays.toString(testsav)+" sorted improperly to "+Arrays.toString(test));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Any comparison-based sort algorithm can be made stable. Simply change the comparison function so that, if the two elements are equal, it compares their *original* indices instead. Since stooge sort is a comparison-based sort this can be applied here as well.

Comment: How about [heap sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)? It is [comparison-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_sorts) but [not stable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19336881/7168030)