# Ordering issue while popping from priority_queue, Is this a bug with std::priority_queue

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std, priority-queue

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

 struct Temp
 {
   int p;
   std::string str;
 };

 struct TempCompare
 {
     bool operator()(Temp const & a, Temp const & b)
     {
         return a.p > b.p;
     }
 };

int main() {

    std::priority_queue<Temp, std::vector<Temp>, TempCompare> pq;
    //Enable and Disable the following line to see the different output
    //{Temp t; t.p=8;t.str="str1";pq.push(t);} 
    {Temp t; t.p=8;t.str="str2";pq.push(t);}
    {Temp t; t.p=9; t.str="str1";pq.push(t);}
    {Temp t; t.p=9; t.str="str2";pq.push(t);}

    while(!pq.empty())
    {
        std::cout << pq.top().p << " " << pq.top().str << std::endl;
        pq.pop();
    }
}
```

Run the above program with enabling and disabling the fourth line in main; The output you get when its disabled is

```
8 str2
9 str1
9 str2
```

whereas when its enabled you get

```
8 str1
8 str2
9 str2
9 str1
```

Shouldnt the behavior be consistent?

Comment: Is there documentation that the sort is "stable" for equal elements?  If not, the behavior seems possible, but not necessarily what you expected.

Comment: There are stable sorting algorithms, like [`std::stable_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort), but [heapsort is not one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336881/why-isnt-heapsort-stable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  There is no reason for the behaviour to be consistent.  `Temp{9, "str1"}` and `Temp{9,"str2"}` are equal according to your comparison function, so they get returned in an arbitrary order.  Adding different elements to the queue is quite likely to change that order.

If you want them returned in a consistent order, you need to extend the comparison function.  The simplest way is

```
     bool operator()(Temp const & a, Temp const & b)
     {
         return std::tie(a.p,a.str) > std::tie(b.p,b.str);
     }
```

If you want "descending in `p`, but ascending in `str`", you'll have to do it yourself.

Comment: "descending in p, but ascending in str" -> `return std::tie(b.p,a.str) < std::tie(a.p,b.str)`