# Sort by two values prioritizing the sort based on one value

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I got a struct pair array whcih consist of timestamp and its occurrence. I want to sort it by the occurrence first, then if they have the same occurrence, sort it by the timestamp.(Both are sort in descending order)

sort by occurrence (completed):

```
1667473200      6
1658390400      6
1672596000      6
1677412800      6
1647604800      5
```

What I want:

```
1677412800      6
1672596000      6
1667473200      6
1658390400      6
1647604800      5
```

My heap sort function(sort by occurrence):

```
void heapify(struct pair *arr, int n, int i)
{
    // Find largest among root, left child and right child
    int largest = i;
    int left = 2 * i + 1;
    int right = 2 * i + 2;

    if (left < n && arr[left].occurrence > arr[largest].occurrence)
        largest = left;

    if (right < n && arr[right].occurrence > arr[largest].occurrence)
        largest = right;

    // Swap and continue heapifying if root is not largest
    if (largest != i)
    {
        swapint(&arr[i].occurrence, &arr[largest].occurrence);
        swaplong(&arr[i].timestamp, &arr[largest].timestamp);
        heapify(arr, n, largest);
    }
}

void heapSort(struct pair *arr, int n)
{
    // Build max heap
    for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        heapify(arr, n, i);

    // Heap sort
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        swapint(&arr[0].occurrence, &arr[i].occurrence);
        swaplong(&arr[0].timestamp, &arr[i].timestamp);
        // Heapify root element to get highest element at root again
        heapify(arr, i, 0);
    }
}
```

How should I modify my heap sort function?

Comment: Write a compare function for your struct that takes into account your conditions (if occurence is equal, compare by timestamp, else compare only by occurence), and pass the data and function to `qsort`.

Comment: In your `heapyfy()` function, add the following if statements after the first two: `if (left < n && arr[left].occurrence == arr[largest].occurrence && arr[left].timestamp > arr[largest].timestamp) largest = left;` and `if (right < n && arr[right].occurrence == arr[largest].occurrence && arr[right].timestamp > arr[largest].timestamp) largest = right;`

Comment: Thanks Zakk!!!!!!! my output is correct now!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a stable sorting algorithm. By applying the algorithm a first time (example Merge sort) you sort the array of struct by occurrences, then apply it a second time by sorting the array by timestamp.

Heap sort non-stability:
[Why-isnt-heapsort-stable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336881/why-isnt-heapsort-stable)

Merge-sort explanation:
[Merge-sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort)